MKMapview overlay renderding performance issue on iOS16
I have following scenario where I feel performance issue.
Use-case:
I have multiple Overlays(MKOverlay) rendered on MapView, and overlay needs to refresh on point Drag(MKPinAnnotation). I have custom logic to handle drag behaviour of annotation, on annotation drag I do update the overlay. As point update, I create new overlay with updated coordinate and re-render it. iT slow down the performance after few overlay added.
Additional Notes: Performance was quite good on iOS16 but on iOS17, it lags the perforce on point drag. When I say it the performance, it point drag lags so it slow the overlay rendering.
I am using MKMapView inside SwiftUI.
I am sharing code-snippet where it re-render the overlay. Please help with issue in my code implementation.
func renderSegments(mapView: MKMapView, segmentPoint: FencePointAnnotation, renderNeeded: Bool = true) {
    mapViewModel.updateFencePointOrder()
    
    guard let activeLayer = mapViewModel.activeLayer else {
        debugPrint("Invalid active layer.")
        return
    }
    let segments = mapViewModel.activeFence.connectedSegmentsOf(vertex: segmentPoint)
    
    // Remove existing overlay.
    for overlay in mapView.overlays {
        if let overlay = overlay as? FenceOverlay {
            if overlay.layerId == activeLayer.layerId {
                mapView.removeOverlay(overlay)
            }
        } else if let overlay = overlay as? FenceSegmentPolyline {
            if overlay.layerId == activeLayer.layerId {
                for segment in segments.values where segment.identifier == overlay.identifier {
                    mapView.removeOverlay(overlay)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // When vertex removed the no need to add segment
    if renderNeeded {
        if let segments = mapViewModel.updatedSegements(segment: segments.map({$0.key})) {
            let updatedSegments = mapView.updatedSegmentsWithOffset(segments: segments, layer: activeLayer)
            mapView.addOverlays(updatedSegments)
        }
    }
}


MKPinAnnotation is deprecated for long time now. Please utilise MKMarkerAnnotation.
